# Derivitive of operation

Tags: functional-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I study semigroups and their application in PDEs, and I'm stuck with an idea that I can't understand.
Let $T(t)$ and $S(t)$ be $C_0$ semigroup of bounded linear operator with the same infinitesimal generator $A$. Then $S = T$.

Proof: 
Let $x\in D(A)$ and 
$U[0;t] \to X $
$\, \,\,\,$   $s\to u(s) = T(t-s)S(s)x $

$\frac{d}{ds}U(s) = 0$ 
So $U$ is a constant
If $U$ was a real or a complex function, it's obvious but $U$ is an operator from $X$ to $X$.

My question is: Who allows us to use the property of derivatives from the real world to the operator world. And if the derivitive of $U$ is $0$, how do we justify, that $U$ is a constant?

Comment: Yes, its clear but the derivitive is zero not implied that the function is constant , unless the function is real or complex we use mean value theorem (or Lagrange theorem) to proof that the function is constant